# Many to many - select collection of entities without determined field and with limited number of results

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have two enitity classes which are in many to many relationship

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "members")
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();

}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Group implements Serializable {
  ...

  @JoinTable(name = "user_groups",
          joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "group_id")},
          inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")})

  private Set<User> members = new HashSet<>();
```

}

When i make a request to get a specific group I get :

```
{
  "id": 12,
  "adminId": 12345,
  "name": "name",
  "category": "cat",
  "city": "city",
  "members": [
    { 
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "SomeName",
      "birthday": 802476000000,
      "city": "SomeCity",
      "country": "SomeCountry",
      "age": 21,
      "groups": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "adminId": 123,
          "name": "Some group name",
          "category": "some category",
          "city": "some city"
        }
      ],
      "picturePath": some path
    }
]
```

}
When i want to get a specific group by id, in its members field i want to have only users without groups field and top 100 rows from database.
Hope you understood : User belongs to many groups and groups have many users

I want to get something like this :

```
{
  "id": 12,
  "adminId": 12345,
  "name": "name",
  "category": "cat",
  "city": "city",
  "members": [
    { 
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "SomeName",
      "birthday": 802476000000,
      "city": "SomeCity",
      "country": "SomeCountry",
      "age": 21,
      "picturePath": some path
    }
]
```

What comes to my mind is to create and Entity class of join table (which has columns : user_id,group_id) and create query that will get results of user_ids for given group_id and then in loop get users with fields that i am interested in

Maybe should I use some Tuple query?
Thanks for your spending time on my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh stupid me :)

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT u.user_id,u.birthdate,u.first_name,u.city,u.country,u.age,u.picture_path " +
                "FROM users u " +
                "INNER JOIN user_groups ug " +
                "ON ug.user_id = u.user_id WHERE ug.group_id = ?",User.class);
```

user_groups is a join table, count of result can be done by using LIMIT (in MySQL)